# Insert row into MapInfo table using c# and MapInfApplication object

Tags: c#, mapinfo

I am attempting to insert a record, then eventually update a record using the MapInfoApplication object in c#.  I can currently read the table contents out into a listbox in a windows forms application no problem, however, writing is proving problematic.

```
MapInfoApplication myMI = new MapInfoApplication();
myMI.Do(@"open table ""\\servername\\directory path\\TestTable2.tab"" as testtable2");
myMI.Do("select * from testtable2 into selection");
int count = int.Parse(myMI.Eval("tableinfo(selection,8)"));
myMI.Do("fetch first from selection");
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(myMI.Eval("selection.col1"));
    myMI.Do("fetch next from selection");
}
```

the above works fine, below does not

```
myMI.Do(@"insert into testtable2(picname) values(""pic 5"")");
myMI.Do(@"commit table testtable2");
//mostly get error like table being edited by another
```

Can anyone assist?

Comment: The error you're getting suggests that the table is already in a state of being edited by another user. Have you confirmed that the table is not being edited? For instance, there should be no TDA, TMA, TID, etc... files alongside the tab file in it's directory.

Comment: Do you get the same error if the table resides locally on your computer?

Comment: Thanks to both of you.  The file did have a lock on it.  I deleted the TDA, TMA and tested both locally and on the server and it now writes correctly.  I have been unable to close the file as yet (I still have to do that manually within MI) so that I can re-open but that'll be the next step.